# How to interpret this minimum expression?

Tags: notation

I am trying to understand the below conditional equation - it comes from Example 1 (Page 9) of A Tutorial on Variable Neighborhood Search (Hansen & Mladenovic, 2003). If more context is needed, find the paper here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2906122_A_Tutorial_on_Variable_Neighborhood_Search

$$\begin{equation}
  x_{ij}=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    1, & \text{if}\ c_{ij}=\min_{\ell|y_\ell=1} c_{\ell j} \text{(with minimum index}\ \ell\ \text{in case of ties)} \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}$$

$\min_{\ell|y_\ell=1} c_{\ell j} \text{(with minimum index}\ \ell\ \text{in case of ties)}$

Could anyone please explain how to interpret this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy it correctly.  It says $$c_{i,j}=\min_{\ell|y_\ell=1} c_{\ell,j},$$ and it means that $i$ is the cheapest cost open facility that can serve customer $j$.

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt - corrected the missing '=1's. I cannot seem to get the conditions on the min to appear underneath.

Comment: What does the | mean please? How would you say the expression in English? I mean, say it with just the variables and not in context to the example.

Comment: $\ell$ such that $y_\ell=1$